# Tensor product of point-determined algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

We say a (commutative, associative, unital) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$ is point-determined if for every nonzero $a\in A$ there is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\chi:A\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\chi(a)\ne0$.

I'm having trouble showing that if $A,B$ are two point-determined $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, so is their tensor product $A\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B$. This is an exercise from the book *Smooth manifolds and observables* by Jet Nestruev.

> My thoughts: if I have a nonzero *pure* tensor, then everything is easy. However, given a general tensor $\sum_ia_i\otimes b_i\ne0$, there is not much I can say about each individual $a_i\otimes b_i$, since in general one cannot tell if a tensor is zero or not. Therefore, I can't produce $f,g$ such that $\sum_if(a_i)g(b_i)\ne0$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to check that if $u\in A\otimes B$ is a non-zero tensor, there exists an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\psi:A\otimes B\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi(u)\neq 0$. Note that if $\alpha:A\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta:B\to \mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphisms, then $\alpha\otimes \beta:A\otimes B\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$(\alpha\otimes \beta)(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\otimes b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha(a_i)\beta(b_i)$$ is a  well-defined $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphsim. We're going to look for $\psi$ of the form $\alpha\otimes \beta$, which OP already knows.

To get around non-uniqueness of representation, we will let $n$ be the **minimum** non-negative integer $m$ such that there exist $a_1',\ldots, a_m'\in A$ and $b_1',\ldots, b_m'\in B$ such that $u=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i'\otimes b_i'$. Since $u\neq 0$, $n\neq 0$.

With this fixed $n$, we can select some $a_{1},\ldots, a_{n}\in A$ and $b_1,\ldots, b_n\in B$ such that $u=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\otimes b_i$.  Note that $a_1\neq 0$, otherwise $u=\sum_{i=2}^n a_i\otimes b_i$ is a representation of $u$ with fewer than $n$ elementary tensors. Fix an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\chi:A\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\chi(a_1)\neq 0$. Note that \begin{align*} u & =a_1\otimes b_1 + \sum_{i=2}^n a_i\otimes b_i = a_1\otimes b_1+\sum_{i=2}^n \Bigl[a_i-\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1+\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1\Bigr]\otimes b_i \\ & = a_1\otimes\Bigl[b_1-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}b_i\Bigr] + \sum_{i=2}^n \Bigl[a_i-\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1\Bigr]\otimes b_i.\end{align*}

Note that $b_1-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}b_i\neq 0$, otherwise the first tensor in the expression above is zero, and we again have a representation of $u$ using at most $n-1$ elementary tensors, contradicting the minimality of $n$. Therefore there exists an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\psi:B\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\psi\Bigl(b_1-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}b_i\Bigr)\neq 0.$$  Then consider $\chi\otimes \psi:A\otimes B\to \mathbb{R}$ which is the unique $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism on $A\otimes B$ taking $a\otimes b$ to $\chi(a)\psi(b)$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Note that $$\chi\Bigl(a_i-\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1\Bigr)=\chi(a_i)-\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}\chi(a_1)=0$$ for all $i=2,\ldots, n$. So \begin{align*} \chi\otimes \psi(u) & = \chi(a_1)\psi\Bigl(b_1-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}b_i\Bigr) +\sum_{i=2}^n \chi\Bigl(a_i-\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1\Bigr)\psi(b_i) \\ & = \chi(a_1)\psi\Bigl(b_1-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}b_i\Bigr) +\sum_{i=2}^n 0\cdot \psi(b_i) \\ & =\chi(a_1)\psi\Bigl(b_1-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}b_i\Bigr) \neq 0.\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent proof! Do you mind sharing some motivation for how you came up with the argument?

Comment: Thanks! Of course. I chose the minimal $n$ because, after lots of time working with tensors, I found that this is often the most convenient way to deal with non-uniqueness of representation. So I started with that, and got lucky that it worked.

Comment: The other major part was we know that for any particular $a_i$, there exists $\chi$ such that $\chi(a_i)\neq 0$. But we only know how to choose these for one $a_i$ at a time (say, $a_1$). Then we want the action of $\chi$ on the other $a_i$ not to ruin the good behavior we get on $a_1$. So we want to modify each other $a_i$ to get something which has zero action under $\chi$ (a la Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization, biorthogonalization, etc.). Subtracting $\chi(a_i)/\chi(a_1)a_1$ is a common way to do this. Luckily in this case, the difference can be swept into the first term, and it works out.

Comment: Honestly, when I first split $a_i= a_i-\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1+\frac{\chi(a_i)}{\chi(a_1)}a_1$, I wasn't quite sure it was going to go anywhere. Just kind of got lucky from there.

Comment: I agree that choosing the minimal expression for the tensor is a useful trick in dealing with tensor products.